# Auto-complete using Tries in Python with OOP

Tags: python, beginner, object-oriented, trie

I am working on a problem to develop auto-complete functionality to practice different applications of Tries. The auto-complete function will return all the possible words in the wordlist given a prefix. I came up with the following solution which returns the result as expected. I need some help to review my code, in order to enhance the OOP structure and improve the code quality over all.

Please let me know your thoughts, any feedback is welcome.

```
class Trie():
    def __init__(self):
        self.children = {}
        self.flag = False # Flag to represent that a word ends at this node

    def insert(self, word):
        for char in word:
            if char not in self.children:
               self.children[char]= Trie()

            self = self.children[char]
        self.flag = True

    def all_suffixes(self, prefix):
        results = set()

        if self.flag:
            results.add(prefix)

        if not self.children: 
            return results

        return reduce(lambda a, b: a | b,  [node.all_suffixes(prefix + char) for (char, node) in self.children.items()]) 

    def autocomplete(self, prefix):
        node = self
        for char in prefix:
            if char not in node.children:
                return None
            node = node.children[char]
        return list(node.all_suffixes(prefix))

if __name__=="__main__":
    word_list = ['aardvark','ark', 'altimeter','altitude', 'apotactic', 'bagonet', 'boatlip', 
    'carburant', 'chyliferous', 'consonance', 'cyclospondylic', 
    'dictyostele', 'echelon', 'estadal', 'flaunty', 'gesneriaceous', 
    'hygienic', 'infracentral', 'jipijapa', 'lipoceratous', 'melanthaceae']

    c = Trie()

    for word in word_list:
        c.insert(word)
    print c.autocomplete('a')
```

Output - `['aardvark', 'ark', 'altimeter', 'altitude', 'apotactic']`

I was thinking on the lines of having two classes one as `Trie()` and the other as `Autocomplete()`. The `__init__(self,word_list)` for `Autocomplete()`  can then have the `for` loop code snippet to create the Trie from the word list.

Comment: Also see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Suffix_tree ; though bit more complex and unnecessary in this case... However, if you are exploring Data structures regarding string manipulations, then it could be helpful

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: @Vogel612 I will keep that in mind, but that snippet `|results` was already in the solution that I was originally referring to and for some reason it got left out while posting the question.

Answer (score 4):

#### Bug

Put `'a'` in `word_list`: it is not found by `autocomplete('a')`. This is because `all_suffixes` doesn't use the `result` variable when building the result in case the node has children.

#### Naming

- The name `self.flag` tells nothing about the purpose of the variable. `self.word_end` would be better.
- `all_suffixes` returns whole words, not suffixes. `words_with_prefix` would be a better name. Alternatively, the function could return suffixes only and adding the prefix would be the responsibility of `autocomplete`.

#### Other

Instead of using a `set` and `reduce` in `all_suffixes`, it would be simpler to use just a `list` and `extend` it in a loop. (There should be no duplicate words in the list anyway, because the trie does not store duplicates)

```
def words_with_prefix(self, prefix):
    results = []
    if self.word_end:
        results.append(prefix)
    for (char, node) in self.children.items():
        results.extend(node.all_suffixes(prefix + char))
    return results
```

Comment: Could you please elaborate on the bug? If you meant that the function should also return 'a', then actually I am only trying to find words that begin with the prefix. So if I pass `autocomplete(art)` and the word list only contained say `artist` then the results would have only `artist` and not `art` itself

Comment: @aamir23 But if both `art` and `artist` are in the list, I would expect to see both in results. Your version only returns `artist`.

Comment: @Jane Karila You are correct, I believed the flag would take care of it indicating a word ends here, but when I tested it right now it only returned `artist`. Thank you for pointing it out and fixing it.